# Как задать полные права доступа для гугл приложения?

Tags: google-app-engine

При запуске приложения открывается браузер и там запрос view calendar, но когда пытаюсь создать запись - insufficion permitions. Вот я и думаю нужно больше прав доступа.

Answer (score 0):

Через scope. 
CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly
или .Calendar